# How can I implement method<T>(T) from an interface

Tags: c#, interface

I am setting up a small infrastructure that I use to communicate with different search systems (e.g. Apache Solr, SQL DB, etc). For each system I have one individual class (="communicator") that implements a common interface, so that the subsequent application can "talk" to all search systems in the same way. Furthermore, each search system has its own class that I use to create the actual query. An object of that individual query class holds all relevant query parameters and is passed to the according communicator class. So for Solr it looks something like this:

```
Solr solr = new Solr();
SolrQuery sQuery = new SolrQuery();
//use some methods on sQuery to specify the query
var result = solr.query(sQuery);
```

So far so good. But how do I specify the query-method in the interface? The Solr class expects an object of type SolrQuery. The MySQL class expects an object of type MySQLQuery.

One solution that does what I want is this: I change the whole interface like this:

```
interface ISearchTechnology<T>
{
  someReturnType query(T queryObject);
}
```

and then change the class definition of Solr (e.g.) to

```
class Solr : ISearchTechnology<SolrQuery>
```

That works. But this makes no sense conceptually. The type SolrQuery is only relevant for this one method (query), not for the whole class. There might be other types (other than SolrQuery, e.g. SolrAnswer) that I need to include. Including all of those like this is confusing and violates my understanding of the concept.

I tried to attach the `<T>` part to the method in the interface (`query<T>(T queryObject)`), but I haven't found any way to actual implement it.

In the end I want to have the following situation: Each communicator class implements the query method as required by the interface, but only accepts one specific type for the parameter that is different from all other communicator classes.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Is it possible for you to provide some reference information on the search systems that you are trying to implement? You talk about SQL DB up there, but that's not very specific. There's already data abstractions provided in .NET through [.NET Data Providers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a6cd7c08.aspx)

Comment: Solr and SQL really are only examples to introduce the dependencies. My question only targets the relationship between an interface, a class that implements it and multiple types that are used as parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach with `ISearchTechnology<T>` is correct, even from conceptual standpoint.

Comment: It seems to me that it *is* an answer to poster's question "But how do I specify the query-method in the interface?".

Comment: Is this really the only option? I find that not intuitive. I want to bind the type only to a single method, not to the whole class.

Comment: Yes it is. Think of it this way: implementation of `ISearchTechnology` for Solr could use only *one* type of query (`SolrQuery`), no matter how many methods will use it. If you decide to add another query method (for example `QuerySingle`) it will use same query type.

Comment: Yes, I know what you mean. My problem is that I might have 100 different types for each communicator class. For Queries, Parameters, Responses, User rights, etc, etc. And I might need each type for only one method. I just want to avoid to have something like that: ISearchTechnology<Type1, Type2, Type3, ..., Type42>

Comment: It seems to me that there's something wrong with your design, if you have 100 different classes for each implementation *and* you need to specify each one in your implementation inteface. Why don't you abstract to interfaces? In fact, that what polymorphism is for.

Answer (score 0):

How about this instead:

```
public interface ITechnology<TQuery, TSearch>
{
    TQuery Query(TQuery queryObject);
    TSearch Search(TSearch saerchObject);
}

public interface ISolrTechnology : ITechnology<SolrQuery, SolrSearch>
{
}

public class Solr : ISolrTechnology
{
    public SolrQuery Query(SolrQuery queryObject) {
        // ...
    }
    public SolrSearch Search(SolrSearch searchObject) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

The `interface ISolrTechnology` is of course optional. `class Solr` could inherit `ITechnology<SolrQuery, SolrSearch>` itself.

Comment: The return types, if variable, could be added to the interface's generic parameters: `ITechnology<TQuery, TQueryResult, TSearch, TSearchType>`.